# How to clear a cell in an org-mode table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Is there a built-in command to delete the contents of a cell in a single keystroke within an org-mode table? Note, I don't want to delete the row, just the cell contents.

```
 | some text |  ==> |             |
```

If not, how would you write this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[`org-table-blank-field`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-table-editor.html#index-C_002dc-SPC-267), present in the “Tbl” menu.

It used to be bound to `C-c SPC`, but [version 9.5](https://github.com/bzg/org-mode/blob/main/etc/ORG-NEWS#the-keybinding-for-org-table-blank-field-has-been-removed) removed that default binding.

It's been around at least since version 6.01 in 2008, but for some reason it was only [added](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/commit/?id=9aa58fa) to the manual [as a consequence of this question](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-11/msg00493.html).

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: It has documented in the doc because of this question.  The commit is http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/commit/?id=9aa58fa .  Requested https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-11/msg00493.html

Comment: `org-table-blank-field` will clear the current line in a cell, but if the cell has multiple lines, it will still only affect the current line

Comment: Note that you can also set the mark with `C-SPC`, move the cursor, and use this command to clear a range of rows and/or columns in one go.

Comment: To reset the binding: `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c SPC") 'org-table-blank-field)`

Answer (score 15):

`org-table-blank-field` as already said, but also if you move to the cell with `TAB`, then typing will clear the cell content and replace it with what you type.